# Suggestion for solving fragile pattern matching

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I often need to match a tuple of values that should have the same constructor. The catchall `_,_` always winds-up at the end. This of course is fragile, any additional constructor added to the type will compile perfectly fine. My current thoughts are to have matches that connect the first but not second argument. But, is there any other options?

For example,

```
type data = | States of int array 
            | Chars  of (char list) array

let median a b = match a,b with
    | States xs, States ys ->
        assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
        States (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> xs.(i) lor ys.(i)))
    | Chars xs, Chars ys -> 
        assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
        let union c1 c2 = (List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x c2)) c1) @ c2 in
        Chars (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> union xs.(i) ys.(i)))
    (* inconsistent pairs of matching *)
    | Chars  _, _
    | States _, _ -> assert false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the slightly shorter pattern below:

```
| (Chars _| States _), _ -> assert false
```

In fact, you can let the compiler generate it for you, because it's still a little tedious.
Type the following and compile:

```
let median a b = match a,b with
| States xs, States ys ->
    assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
    States (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> xs.(i) lor ys.(i)))
| Chars xs, Chars ys -> 
    assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
    let union c1 c2 = (List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x c2)) c1) @ c2 in
    Chars (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> union xs.(i) ys.(i)))
```

> Warning 8: this pattern-matching is
>   not exhaustive. Here is an example of
>   a value that is not matched: (Chars _,
>   States _)

You can now copy-paste the suggested pattern back into your code. This is usually how I generate non-fragile catch-all patterns for types with tens of constructors. You may need to launch the compiler several times, but it's still faster than typing them yourself.

Comment: Interesting! This strategy is probably something that should be built into Haskell IDEs?

Comment: Well, I'd rather not have all those compile warnings --an additional one would get lost in the shear number that would be produced. I actually had no idea you can do `or` matches within tuples like that. That should save some lines, thanks.

Comment: @nlucaroni In case I did not make that clear, I am only suggesting to get the warning temporarily because it contains a catch-all non-fragile pattern to copy-paste back into the code.

Comment: @Jörg In case someone decides to do that, another instance of the same trick is to write `val f:unit` in the signature of a module where f is in fact a function with a complicated type that you do not feel confident writing yourself. The error message contains the type of `f` as implemented in the module. Not sure how that one translates to Haskell, though.

Comment: @Pascal: I don't know Ocaml, but I think that translates to writing `f :: ()` as the type signature for some `f = ...` (`()` being the Haskell spelling of `unit`) where you'd like to see the error.  Or just leaving off the type signature and running `:t f` in GHCi, if you're using GHC.

Comment: @Antal, Yes, that is correct. Actually, `()` is the value of `unit` in ocaml and `unit` is the type. There are other ways that the compiler can help too, the (bytecode and native) `ocaml` compiler  option `-i` will write to `stdout` the types for all the functions in a given file.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hackish (and results in warnings) but you can use `Obj` to check if the tags are equal or not.  It should catch all cases where a and b have different values:

```
type data = | States of int array 
            | Chars  of (char list) array

let median a b = match a,b with
    | States xs, States ys ->
        assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
        States (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> xs.(i) lor ys.(i)))
    | Chars xs, Chars ys -> 
        assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
        let union c1 c2 = (List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x c2)) c1) @ c2 in
        Chars (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> union xs.(i) ys.(i)))
    (* inconsistent pairs of matching *)
    | x, y when (Obj.tag (Obj.repr x)) <> (Obj.tag (Obj.repr y)) -> assert false
```

The warning is for non-exhaustive pattern-matching (since it can't tell whether or not the guarded clause matches the rest or not).

EDIT: you don't need to use Obj at all, you can just compare x and y directly:

```
| x, y when x <> y -> assert false
```

Though this still results in a warning, unfortunately.

Comment: In my opinion, the very point of these warning is not to ensure that the execution goes all right, but that you will get warned, if you change the datatype, to reconsider this pattern and possibly implement a new behavior adapted to the changes. Your technique is dynamically clever, but doesn't give those useful warnings (or turn them into noise) that very much help maintainability.

Comment: My solution is even worse than that!  It doesn't take into account constant Constructors.  I'm going to edit it for that, but yeah, losing the value of warnings is almost certainly not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of taste/style, but I tend to prefer grouping clauses on the same constructor together, rather than having the useful clauses for everything first, then all the "absurd cases" together. This can be quite helpful when you get to write several "useful" clauses for one given constructor, and want to check you didn't forget anything.

```
let median a b = match a,b with
  | States xs, States ys ->
    assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
    States (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> xs.(i) lor ys.(i)))
  | States _, _ -> assert false

  | Chars xs, Chars ys -> 
    assert( (Array.length xs) = (Array.length ys) );
    let union c1 c2 = (List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x c2)) c1) @ c2 in
    Chars (Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> union xs.(i) ys.(i)))
  | Chars _, _ -> assert false
```