# How to check whether two values are created with the same constructor?

Tags: ocaml

let's say I have

```
type t = A of int | B of int

let xx = A(2);;
let yy = A(3);;
```

and I want to test if the constructors of xx and yy are equal,
is there an easy way to do this ? Instead of having to

```
match xx with
  A _ ->
  (match yy with A _ -> true | B _ -> false)
| B _ -> 
  (match yy with A _ -> false | B _ -> true);;
```

which gets quite messy when there many constructors on a type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rewrite the above to, somewhat simpler:

```
match xx, yy with
| A _, A _
| B _, B _ -> true
| (A _ | B _), _ -> false
```

but I'm not aware of a solution without enumerating all the constructors.

Comment: This is correct, although, it is often wise to avoid `_,_` and better to use, `(A _ | B _ ), _`. In this way, if the constructor changes the compiler can help you in finding errors. There is a discussion on this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346901/suggestion-for-solving-fragile-pattern-matching

Comment: it can be done by comparing values' tags (rather safe with proper type annotations) :)

Comment: @niucaroni: indeed, very good point. I took the liberty to incorporate it into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible, sort of, through the `Obj` module. Analyzing objects through the `Obj` functions, if done properly, won't crash your program; but you need to be careful if you want to get meaningful results.

```
let equal_constructors (x : 'a) (y : 'a) =
  let r = Obj.repr x and s = Obj.repr y in
  if Obj.is_int r && Obj.is_int s then (Obj.obj r : int) = (Obj.obj s : int) else
  if Obj.is_block r && Obj.is_block s then Obj.tag r = Obj.tag s else
  false
```

When called on values of a variant type (not a polymorphic variant type), this function returns `true` if the two values both have the same zero-argument constructor or both have the same 1-or-more-argument constructor, and `false` otherwise. The type system won't prevent you from instanciating `equal_constructors` at other types; you'll get a `true` or `false` return value but not necessarily a meaningful one.

Comment: this is a somewhat ugly low-level hack, and very dependent on details of the implementation of the compiler.  The solution below is preferable.

Comment: @yzzlr The specification of the C interface guarantees the representation properties that my code relies on. So yes, it's an ugly low-level hack, but what it depends on is part of the documented behavior of the (only) implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this that can work well is to create another type that corresponds to the tags, and use that type.

```
type t = A of int | B of int
module Tag = struct type t = A | B end

let to_tag = function A _ -> Tag.A | B _ -> Tag.B
let tags_are_equal x y =
    to_tag x = to_tag y
```