# Checking that two values have the same head constructor

Tags: haskell

I'd like to be able to write a function which checks that two values have been built using the same head constructor. This function:

- shouldn't be linear in the size of the datatype declaration
- should keep working if the datatype is extended

e.g. this is not satisfactory (it is linear and the catchall will invalidate the function if I add any extra constructor):

```
data E = A Int | B String | C

sameCons :: E -> E -> Bool
sameCons t u = case (t, u) of
  (A{}, A{}) -> True
  (B{}, B{}) -> True
  (C{}, C{}) -> True
  _          -> False
```

In OCaml [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522360/how-to-check-whether-two-values-are-created-with-the-same-constructor/6528149#6528149) to use unsafe functions from the `Obj` module to do exactly that. Can we do something similar in Haskell (a ghc-specific solution works too)?

Comment: Could you make your type an instance of `Data`?

Comment: You're making an assumption about operational aspects of the compiler implementation when you say that your example is "linear". GHC for instance expands the case on tuple to nested cases, which in turn will be compiled to either a jump table or binary search

Comment: It's linear in number of lines of code that must be written, without making any assumptions about GHC.

Comment: @amalloy ah yeah I guess that's a better interpretation of what op meant

Comment: I guess you're trying to keep it simple, but it strikes me that returning a `Bool` from such a test is underpowered. It's interesting to consider how to extract from a positive outcome the useful information that the constructor arguments can be paired up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to derive [`Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data) then you're good to go.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data E = A Int | B String | C deriving (Typeable, Data)

sameCons :: E -> E -> Bool
sameCons x y = toConstr x == toConstr y

ghci> sameCons (A 1) (A 3)
True
ghci> sameCons (A 1) (C)
False
```

Comment: `sameCons :: Data a => a -> a -> Bool; sameCons = (==) \`on\` toConstr`

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `GHC.Generics`, but it's more boilerplate than The Orgazoid's answer.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Function (on)
import GHC.Generics

class GSameCons f where
  gSameCons :: f p -> f p -> Bool

instance GSameCons f => GSameCons (D1 c f) where
  gSameCons (M1 a) (M1 b) = gSameCons a b

instance (GSameCons f, GSameCons g) => GSameCons (f :+: g) where
  gSameCons (L1 a) (L1 b) = gSameCons a b
  gSameCons (R1 a) (R1 b) = gSameCons a b
  gSameCons _ _ = False

instance GSameCons (C1 c f) where
  gSameCons _ _ = True

data E = A Int | B String | C deriving Generic

sameCons :: (GSameCons (Rep a), Generic a) => a -> a -> Bool
sameCons = gSameCons `on` from

main = do
  print (sameCons (A 1) (A 2))
  print (sameCons (B "") C)
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up needing a datatype of constructor names anyway so here is our current solution which does not rely on `Data` or `GHC.Generics`:

```
data E = A Int | B String | C
data EName = A_ | B_ | C_ deriving (Eq)

eName :: E -> EName
eName e = case e of
  A{} -> A_
  B{} -> B_
  C{} -> C_

sameCons :: E -> E -> Bool
sameCons = (==) `on` eName
```